# Scrolling to anchor and make nav fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a nav with anchor links fixed when scrolling to an anchor. 
Making things fixed an scroll to an anchor is not the problem.

The problem is that my nav is almost on the bottom of the screen. So what happens if you scroll down the nav gets a `fixed` class. When then clicking an anchor link the script scrolls to far to the anchor block. I tried offsetting the nav to the height of the navigation. That works but only when you click a second time on the same link. First time clicking an anchor link still makes the link scroll too far!

**I created a Fiddle to explain what happens -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meules/wcmoLe5j/2/)**

I personally think that the scrollTo and making the nav fixed at the same time is interfering with each other.

Does anybody know what can cause this?

What I have is this:

```
<div class="anchor-links">
    <div class="anchor-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="#description" class="goSmoothly">Product information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bundles" class="goSmoothly">Product bundles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reviews" class="goSmoothly">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#related" class="goSmoothly">Related products</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="description" class="block">description</div>
<div id="bundles" class="block">bundles</div>
<div id="reviews" class="block">reviews</div>
<div id="related" class="block">related</div>

var fixmeTop = $('.anchor-links').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop){
        $('.anchor-links').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('.anchor-links').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});

$('.goSmoothly').click(function(event){     
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 100
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: one of the problems maybe is the fact that you give fixed position to the anchors while scrolling and the body loses that height so the maths will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var fixmeTop = $('.anchor-links').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop){
        $('.anchor-links').addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $('.anchor-links').removeClass("sticky");
    }
});

$('.goSmoothly').click(function(event){  
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if( $('.anchor-links').hasClass("sticky")) {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 100
    }, 500);
    } else {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 220
    }, 500);    
    }
});
```

```css
.block{
    height:700px;
    background:#eee;
}
.anchor-links {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.anchor-links .nav-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4.2rem;
}
.anchor-links.sticky {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img width="400" height="400" alt="Adidas 2 Opties" itemprop="image" class="featured" data-original-url="http://static.webshopapp.com/shops/057743/files/029936946/adidas-2-opties.jpg" src="http://static.webshopapp.com/shops/057743/files/029936946/400x400x2/adidas-2-opties.jpg">
<div class="anchor-links">
    <div class="anchor-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="#description" class="goSmoothly">Product information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bundles" class="goSmoothly">Product bundles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reviews" class="goSmoothly">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#related" class="goSmoothly">Related products</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="description" class="block">description</div>
<div id="bundles" class="block">bundles</div>
<div id="reviews" class="block">reviews</div>
<div id="related" class="block">related</div>
```

Now, on the else, you can make the -220 dynamic by the size of the `header` before fixing it less the size of the header after fixing.

Like I told you in the comment, the fact that you are removing the header from the body and fixing it, reduces the scroll top of each section.

You have also an option to add a placeholder when the header is fixed, that way you'll prevent the math's mess.

Comment: it looks like this is what I'm looking for. What do you mean by making the -220 dynamic? Do you have an example? Do you know a better way of accomplishing what I'm trying to do? I'm asking since you refer to "math's mess" :) ISn't this a good approach?

Comment: @Meules depends on your page, by -220 dynamic I mean being calculated with the header height by grabbing it from the element. if you add a placeholder in the header non-fixed placed, the math is the same because the body doesnt change of height

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcmoLe5j/3/).

HTML:

```
<div class="anchor-links">
    <div class="anchor-wrapper">
        <ul class="nav-list">
            <li><a href="#description" class="goSmoothly">Product information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bundles" class="goSmoothly">Product bundles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#reviews" class="goSmoothly">Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#related" class="goSmoothly">Related products</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div id="description" class="block">description</div>
<div id="bundles" class="block">bundles</div>
<div id="reviews" class="block">reviews</div>
<div id="related" class="block">related</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
.block{
    height:700px;
    background:#eee;
}
.anchor-links {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
}
.anchor-links .nav-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 4.2rem;
}
.anchor-links.sticky {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: this still gives me the same result! I will look further erhaps there's a CSS conflict.